# How can I check whether a key exists in TOML with toml-rs?

Tags: rust

I have a TOML document in which some keys may or may not exist. E.g. this document is a valid document:

```
foo = "bar"
```

But also this is valid:

```
foo = "bar"
something = "else"
```

I am now trying to parse this document in Rust with the library [toml-rs](https://docs.rs/toml/0.5.3/toml/index.html). However I could not find any guidance in the documentation on how to find out whether a key actually exists in my TOML document. Whenever I try to access this key the program panics with the error `index not found`.

I came up with the following minimalistic example that shows that the Rust code immediately fails when I try to access a key that does not exist:

```
use toml::Value;

fn main() {
    let value = "foo = 'bar'".parse::<Value>().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", value["foo"]);
    println!("{}", "before");
    println!("{:?}", value["foo2"]);
    println!("{}", "after");
}
```

Which leads to the output:

```
String("bar")
before
thread 'main' panicked at 'index not found', src/libcore/option.rs:1034:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

In the actual code of the library I found [a comment for a function called `get`](https://docs.rs/toml/0.5.3/src/toml/value.rs.html#76) that states:

> Also returns `None` if the given key does not exist in the map or the given index is not within the bounds of the array.

However, I am not sure whether this should also apply to my key access. At least to my tests it does not. I was also unable to find a function in the code that would check whether a key exists.

I guess there must be some way to find out whether a key exists in the TOML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` and what you are doing are two completely different paths into the library. This by-key access is [an implementation of `Index<_>`](https://docs.rs/toml/0.5.3/toml/map/struct.Map.html#impl-Index<%26%27a%20Q>) and **will panic** if the key does not exist.

This is what you are seeing in your code.

The **real** way to do what you are trying to do is indeed by using `get()`, which will return an `Option`, but first, we're going to sort out the case where the `toml` you feed *isn't* a table, like so:

```
use toml::{Value};
use toml::map::Map;

fn main() {
    let value = "foo = 'bar'".parse::<Value>().ok().and_then(|r| match r {
        Value::Table(table) => Some(table),
        _ => None
    }).unwrap_or(Map::new()); // This now contains a HashMap<String, Value>
    println!("{:?}", value.get("foo"));
    println!("{}", "before");
    println!("{:?}", value.get("foo2"));
    println!("{}", "after");
}
```